# Why is keydown triggering but keyup is not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
     if (e.shiftKey) {
          $('body').append('test1');
     }
});
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
     if (e.shiftKey) {
          $('body').append('test');
     }
});
```

keyup never triggers for me but keydown does, why is that?

Comment: Hmmm very odd. Same thing here.

Comment: On a serious note... [they both fire fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ktvg8/)

Comment: -1 The fact that you assumed the handler never triggers shows that you didn't perform even the most basic debugging. I've no idea why people are upvoting this.

Answer (score 4):

`event.shiftKey` always return `false` on keyup.

Check for `keyCode === 16` instead (which is the shift key code, on keyup):

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
     if (e.shiftKey) {
          $('body').append('test1');
     }
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode === 16) {
          $('body').append('test');
     }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/eyX5N/

Answer (score 2):

`e.shiftKey` always return `false` when used in the keyUp event... Your event fires, the test just fails.

Comment: How would I effectively detect when the shiftKey released then?

Comment: cfr answer from Neal, more complete than mine :-)

Comment: I thought it was a specific shift that failed, like the left one.